# Replicate Google+ "add comment" effect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to replicate the google+ effect for the add comment feature on each post.

When you click on the "add comment" field, automatically the form appears with buttons and a text-area for your comment.

Is it possible to accomplish it using jquery? Has anyone seen anything like that in other sites and perhaps can point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A no-brainer would be `.toggle()`. Read the docs [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).